# UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD Error in JCL

Tags: zos, jcl

I tried to run this following JCL program using IBM z/OS

```
//PAYMENT JOB MSGCLASS=H
//PAYMENT  EXEC PGM=PAYMENT,REGION=1024K                          
//             PARM='CSQ1,CARD.PAYMENTS,IND0163.REPLY,IND0163     
//             5999.99,"MY PAYMENT"'                              
//STEPLIB  DD DSN=ZOS.CONTEST3.PART2.LOAD,DISP=SHR                
//         DD DSN=WMQ.V6R0.SCSQLOAD,DISP=SHR                      
//         DD DSN=WMQ.V6R0.SCSQANLE,DISP=SHR                      
//         DD DSN=WMQ.V6R0.SCSQAUTH,DISP=SHR                      
//STDOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                            
//STDERR   DD SYSOUT=*                                            
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
```

but after submission of the job ,when I'm trying to view the job output using SDSF , I'm getting **IEFC605I UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD** on line 3 and 4 !! can anyone tell me what's wrong with my program ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try ending lines 2 and 3 with a comma so the JCL reader knows that these lines are not yet complete (ie. continue on the following line).

```
//PAYMENT JOB MSGCLASS=H
//PAYMENT  EXEC PGM=PAYMENT,REGION=1024K,                        <== continued...                 
//             PARM='CSQ1,CARD.PAYMENTS,IND0163.REPLY,IND0163,   <== continued...   
//             5999.99,"MY PAYMENT"'                              
//STEPLIB  DD DSN=ZOS.CONTEST3.PART2.LOAD,DISP=SHR                
//         DD DSN=WMQ.V6R0.SCSQLOAD,DISP=SHR                      
//         DD DSN=WMQ.V6R0.SCSQANLE,DISP=SHR                      
//         DD DSN=WMQ.V6R0.SCSQAUTH,DISP=SHR                      
//STDOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                            
//STDERR   DD SYSOUT=*                                            
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
```

Comment: HAHA !!! thank you so much friend !! I'm really a douche !! missed the comma :P though I've just started learning JCL :P